# How to use tooltip in ReactJS, in JSX, without using npm-module or react-bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap4 in Reactjs project, I installed bootstrap4 using npm and giving module path-link in `App.js`, as

`import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`

but while using tooltip, using inline styling to an icon, I can't give attribute `data-toggle` because of `-` in between them and JSX considers it two different components.

[image: screenshot]

I read we can give tooltip by third party module or separate component, but I wanted to implement inline styles.

here is a code of it.

```
<Link to={`contact/edit/${id}`}>
                  <i
                    className="fas fa-pencil-alt "
                    style={{
                      data-toggle="tooltip", data-placement="top", title="Tooltip-not-working!",
                      cursor: "pointer",
                      float: "right",
                      color: "green",
                      marginRight: "1rem"
                    }}
                  />
                </Link>
```

error is due to not giving attributes as single string.

[image: screenshot]

[my GitHub code-link.](https://github.com/ganesh-deshmukh/friends-list/blob/master/src/components/friends/Friend.js)

Comment: style should have camel case pattern of attribute in react js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're giving attributes through the `style` tag.
It should look like this instead:

`<i data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip-not-working!" style={{...}} />`

Answer (score 1):

You place attribute at wrong place. style attribute should have only camelCase property like marginTop not margin-top. and rest of the props are you passing to element should be same as html.

```
<i data-toggle="Your Message" style={{marginTop: '5px'}} />
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but I used other answer and forgot to accept/ mark as right. your answer also works. upvoted.+1